# java - How to invoke JFileChooser from inside of SwingWorker doInBackground and wait for answer?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

My SwingWorker doInBackground reads several Excel files and performs some lengthy calculations. The files have default names and locations, but when the default file is not found I need to show Open File dialog and wait until the user select the replacement file.
I've tried to use publish() and my Open.. dialog appears nicely, but doInBackground continues the execution and does not wait. How can I accomplish it?

```
private class DataTask extends SwingWorker<Void,Object>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws InterruptedException  {
    int progress = 0;

    setProgress(0);

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
       processDescText = "read file "+i+"...";

       try {
            File f = new File(fileName[i]);
            if(!f.exists()) {
               // here I need to show open file dialog and wait for input
               // ...
               fileName[i] = userInput;
            }
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName[i]);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            fis.close();
            setProgress(i);

           // perform my calculations here 
        }         
        catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Normally you use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`. Not sure whether `SwingWorker.doInBackground()` has some restriction about using that method, though.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, don't. This would violate the single thread rules of Swing. Instead, gather a `List` of files before hand, prompting the user as required; once you have the `List` of files, simply pass it to the `SwingWorker`.

The `SwingWorker` should only focus on processing the files, anything else should generate an exception.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot build such `List`because the calculation results determine which files should be read next, so it's not an option here...

Comment: Then you need to chain each result to another SwingWorker, using either a PropertyChangeListener or the done method to determine when the worker is completed

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a `boolean` that stores whether the `JFileChooser` is done, and in the `doInBackground()` call `wait()` in a `while` loop with its condition as the `boolean`. When your `JFileChooser` is done, set the `boolean` to `true` and call `notifyAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Vanza stated above, you can use SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait.  Can't directly call Swing GUI functions inside the method SwingWorker.doInBackground because by design, the code inside this method will not be running in the Event Dispatch Thread. In fact an exception will be thrown if this method runs in an event dispatch thread.  Swing GUI's can only be updated in the Event Dispatch Thread.

```
class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {
    boolean answer = false;
    public Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("doInBackground  >" + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() + "<");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            answer = false;
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Start loading ?", "Confirm Load", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        answer = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            System.out.println("Answer = " + answer);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```